# Why do the police suspect Antwon Mitchell before he has committed any crime?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-shield

Antwon Mitchell is introduced in the show as a peaceful former gangster, who works for his community.

Yet the police (Monica Rawling and the Strike Team) decide that he must be condemned and sent back to jail before the viewer has been shown any misbehaviour from him.

Other antagonists in *The Shield* are often introduced in the show by committing crimes, that the police find out about later.

Why are the police so quick to assume Antwon Mitchell is guilty?

Comment: I suspect the answer begins with "r" and ends in "acial profiling", but I'm not familiar enough with the show and don't want to jump to conclusions.

Comment: Far too long since I saw it to remember, but https://theshield.fandom.com/wiki/Antwon_Mitchell says Rawling was the one who sent him down the first time, so they have prior. Perhaps avoid reading past the opening paragraph titled Season Four if you've never seen it before.